# Mutil-tasks programming with C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I know the basic of C# programming but my intention is to develop a data acquisition program. Normally I can just use LabVIEW or MATLAB but I would like to learn how to use.NET. Although my knowledge is limited, I understand I will need to know some of the advanced topics in C# like multithreading, async/await, etc. I am learning well through example but the examples I found so far did not help me well. I did not say they were bad examples, just my mental mind did not absorb them well.

I need help with a working example so I can understand these topics.  I have a Winform with 3 textboxes: textbox1, textbox2, textbox3 and 6 buttons. Assume I would like my program to run 3 independent task as following

- textbox1 = show a current time and get updated every 1 second. It
  runs when I hit btStart1 and stop btStop1.
- textbox2 = show a current time and get updated every 2 seconds. It
  runs when I hit btStart2 and stop btStop2.
- textbox3 = show a current time and get updated every 3 seconds. It
  runs when I hit btStart3 and stop when I hit btStop3.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This will happen naturally if you just setup the time event properly. It's handler will run as a separate "task".

Comment: You can use 3 dispatcher timers to do this. You dont need multithreading there/

Comment: For this you wouldnt need true multi threading however, if you're gonna be faking actual processing of something interesting, its worth looking at threading. you should find a number of good examples out there

Comment: Yes, I just want to see a "fake" simple example in this case.   I will need to read multiple voltage channels at very high sample rates and the # samples I need to acquire are also high. These channels can be on the same devices or can be on different devices. That why I feel multiple threads could be a solution (also I need to learn how to distinct async vs thread).

Comment: It looks like you don't need multi-threading at all, just 3 timers that fire at 1, 2 and 3 second intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the basics before you jump to multi-threading without knowing whether it is necessary. Both LabView and Matlab implemented the multi-threading for you so you don't have to worry about it. For C# this is not the case and you need to do some programming at an advanced level to get it correct. For somebody new to C# and more thinking in LabView or Matlab style I would not recommend this.

Beside that point you don't need (probably even can't) multi-thread the data acquisition. Assuming you use the driver from a manufacturer, this driver will determine if you can multi-thread your acquisition, if the communication goes over one cable probably not. You can multi-thread the processing of the acquired data but you first need to check if this is needed.

This hopefully answers partly your question, if you want help with the example you need to post code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips